# How To Use The Where & Like Operator Together in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, where-clause, sql-like

I want to display a List of Instructors with only first name and last name, from Georgia and whose last name ends in ‘son’.

I have written this so far:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, state
FROM instructors
WHERE state = 'ga'
AND lastname LIKE '%son'
```

But it is not returning the information requested just a blank table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Syntactically, that looks almost correct -- you should use `'%son'` to find last names ending in "son". Unless your database's collation is case-sensitive and the state is actually 'GA', we would need to see sample data or a reproducible set of code.

Comment: I was having trouble trying to paste the table here in the question ... any advice?

Comment: What does `SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(lastname, char(10), 'CHAR10'), char(13), 'CHAR13') + '!!!' FROM instructors` give you?  Does that actually show 'CHAR10' or 'CHAR13' or extra spaces between the end of the last name and the exclamation points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FINALLY !!!!!

I Figured It Out!

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, state
FROM instructors
WHERE state = 'ga'
AND lastname LIKE '*son*'
```

Instead of using the %WildCard I inserted *WildCard on both ends and it displayed exactly what I was requesting !

Thanks Everyone For Your Help!

Answer (score 4):

To find names ending in 'son' you need to make a small change and remove the second '%' sign.  with both it looks for 'son' any where such as 'sonnentag'

The second one I would guess that the DB has Georgia as 'GA' not 'ga'.  Case is important.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, state
FROM instructors
WHERE state = 'GA'
AND lastname LIKE '*son'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a formatted comment that shows you how to troubleshoot.  Start with this:

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, state
FROM instructors
WHERE 1 = 1
-- and state = 'ga'
--AND lastname LIKE '%son'
```

If that returns no records, you have no data.  If it does, uncomment the two other filters, one at a time, to see which one causes no records to be returned.  It could well be that you simply have no matching records

Comment: I actually have 2 records that are GA and the last names end in SON.

Answer (score -1):

This should works to you.

```
 SELECT [firstname],[Lastname],[state]
 FROM instructors AS i
 WHERE i.state = 'ga' AND i.lastname LIKE '%son'
```

Comment: Other than adding a table alias, that's *identical* to what they already have, which doesn't work.  Also, the user has updated that this is MS Access